# How to query a Teradata table temporally

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, versioning

I am trying to query a table in teradata based on a person's id and when they took a survey. The problem is, this table does not have a timestamp. I want to instead try to use Teradata's "AS OF" functionality to query the table for each id "as of" the date they took the survey, since the table does have versioning. Is there some way to do this for a range of dates and id's without? I am currently doing this in SAS, as well.

The table is updated every so often to reflect current records. It would show what sort of data might be associated with a given person's id as of today. Teradata allows for versioning, so I can perform a query like

```
 CREATE table  AS 
   VALIDTIME AS OF /*input date here*/
   SELECT *
   FROM table
   WHERE id in /*input list of id's here*/;
```

I would like to do this for a list of dates and a list of id's.
The resulting dataset might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: If there are no timestamps how's the versioning done? Only Temporal Tables allow temporal Selects. Can you show some example data and expected result?

Comment: What you mean that the table has versioning?  How can you have versioning with no dates/timestamps?

Comment: Afaik only a single point in time can be specified for VALIDTIME. But you could apply those dates manually like this: `nonsequenced validtime select ..... where date1 between validfrom and validto or date2 between validfrom and validto or ...`